# Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jakarta-ee, refresh

i have an ajax call which return a List of data, but i have some troubles to refresh my table, i know they are already many topics on this subject and i read all of them and i didn't find the solution.
Here's my Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("change", "#process", function() {  
    var process=$('#process').val();
    var lignes=$('#lignes').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url : "/tps_assy-web/equilibrageReloadTableOperation",
        data:{lignes: lignes, process: process},
        success: function(json){  
            $('#tableAvant').ajax.reload(null, false);
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

and my table is :

```
<table id="tableAvant" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
 <tr>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Ordre</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Nom Pross</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Verbe</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Nom Op</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Mini</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Maxi</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Tps Total</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Tps Mesure</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Tps Retour</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">TDA</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">% Opera</div></th>
     <th class="text-center "><div class="rotate ">Loc Avant</div></th>
</tr>
<tbody>
 <tr th:each="LIST : ${LigneAvant}">
    <td  th:text="${LIST[0]}" ></td>
    <td th:text="${LIST[1]}" ></td>
    <td  th:text="${LIST[2]}" ></td>
    <td th:text="${LIST[3]}" ></td> 
    <td  th:text="${LIST[4]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[5]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[6]}" ></td>    
    <td  class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[7]}" ></td>
    <td  class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[8]}" ></td>
    <td  class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[9]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[14]}" ></td>
    <td class="ellipsis" th:text="${LIST[15]}" ></td>   
     </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

I only need helps on this precise sentence :

```
$('#tableAvant').ajax.reload(null, false);
```

I already try :

```
$('#tableAvant').dataTable( ).api().ajax.reload();
```

and

```
$('#tableAvant').DataTable( ).api().ajax.reload();
```

but that wasn't successful ...

Comment: Have you included the datatables js file?

Comment: Hummm no, I didn't, I will include it and I'll let you know if it succeed

Comment: It is a plugin for JQuery, not native, so ajax will be undefined, hence the reload of undefined

Comment: Ok it doesn't change anything because i aready had an include of jquery in my header, thanks anyway !

Comment: Not include of jquery, you also need to include DataTables: https://datatables.net/

Comment: I include "datatables.min.js", it recognize the function datatable, but i had another error : 
"Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my mistake was not to include

```
<script th:src="@{/js/datatables.min.js}"></script>
```

Also my table wasn't well formed, to use this script you need to have a table which looks like this :

```
<table id="exemple">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>title-1</th>
            <th>title-2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data-1</td>
            <td>data-2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks guys for your help, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this usage type of AJAX but having a quick look online I think I may have the problem. It looks like .ajax.reload() can only be called on a DataTable object where as your example is just getting called on an element.

I suspect you are close with `$('#tableAvant').DataTable().ajax.reload(null, false);` but try pass `{ ajax: "data.json" }` through to the DataTable object.

EG:
`$('#tableAvant').DataTable({ajax: "data.json"}).ajax.reload(null, false);`

Comment: I tried it and i have another error :
"Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined"

Comment: Ok i know why i got this error, it's because of my second include wich is bad.I'll try to remove it and try again